# how to get number of columns in a table using dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Alter proc sp_Get_all_the_details
(
@tablename varchar(20)
)
as
begin

Declare 
@sqlQueryNoofcolumns Nvarchar(1000)
set @sqlQueryNoofcolumns =  'select count(*) from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where TABLE_NAME = ' + @tablename
Execute sp_executesql @sqlQueryNoofcolumns
end

exec sp_Get_all_the_details emp
```

Comment: I've removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Whats wrong with your attempt?

Comment: @EzLo What's wrong with this attempt? Uhm... It 1) uses dynamic SQL without any need, 2) forgets to frame the `@tablename` with quotes, it 3) uses a SP without any need, 4) does not address the `TABLE_SCHEMA` and 5) it names the SP with `sp_` ;-)

Comment: @Shnugo I know there were some problems but I was expecting the OP to explain a little to show interest in the question.

Comment: @EzLo Yes, this question is really poorly articulated. But - to be honest - I think the OP is not experienced enough to point to the problems himself...

Answer (score 2):

Just one thing in advance about your own code:

This line

```
set @sqlQueryNoofcolumns =  
'select count(*) from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where TABLE_NAME = ' + @tablename
```

will translate to

```
select count(*) from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where TABLE_NAME = SomeTableName
```

But without quotes the part `SomeTableName` will not be taken as a string literal. You'd have to add quotes to the dynamic creation like

```
... where TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tablename + ''';' --you have to double the quotes *within* a string...
```

### But the actual answer comes here

This is a typical case, where a stored procedure is the wrong tool to do this. You can cut your bread with a chain saw, it will work, but don't complain about the results...  SPs are meant **to do** something. For a **read-only** issue VIEWs or inline-TVF are much better.

Furthermore, you should not name your own SPs with `sp_`. This is reserved and might lead into troubles... [Details here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

And last but not least: This does not need any dynamic sql...

Try this:

**Hint**: I include the schema as there can be two tables with the same name and this would aggregate in the result...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetAllTheDetails
(
     @SchemaName VARCHAR(250)
    ,@TableName VARCHAR(250)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT c.* 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=ISNULL(@SchemaName,'dbo') AND c.TABLE_NAME=@TableName;
GO
```

--With such a query you will get all the columns

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetAllTheDetails('dbo','SomeTableName');
```

--And this query will return the column count

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.GetAllTheDetails('dbo','SomeTableName');
```

The biggest advantage of iTVFs and VIEWs: You can use them just as any normal table in your queries, in the `FROM` clause, in `JOIN`s - wherever you want. Using the result of a SP is a rather clumsy mess...